Adding bot in standard channels in MS Teams
I have been trying to add my bot application in MS Teams programmatically by using the below API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/members
But, I keep on getting the following error

Error adding bot to channel
code: 'BadRequest',
message: 'Operation not supported for this Channel',
innerError:{
code: 'InvalidRequest',
message: 'Operation not supported for this Channel',
}


In short, what I'm trying to do is add my bot in all channels. Can someone provide an input.
How can I add the bot in all 1:1 chats programmatically without manual work?
Is it even possible

Thanks.

Currently it is not possible to add an app automatically to all chats and channels across tenant. There is no alternative available for this.

However, please refer these Graph APIs to add app to specific users, chats, teams etc.

Please refer this doc for Proactive app installation in Teams -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet#proactive-app-installation-in-teams

hi. I can see APIs to add the 'app into my chats'. Are there APIs to add my bot app into channels?? I can add them teams but I want it to be installed into channels to make my solution work. Is it possible? I basically don't want any user to manually add it.

I am getting this error while using chat APIs to add app in the chat.
"code: 'Forbidden',
message: 'Caller is not authorized.'"
The API used is:
const url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/${chatId}/installedApps;

Currently there is no API endpoint to add an app into channel directly. For the second issue, could you please confirm if you have given the required permissions mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions
